# Give view access to DashBoards in Salesforce

Tags: profile, dashboard, access, view

how to add view access to Dashbord in Salesforce for a profile? Why user cant see this dashboard? It is in public folder and on a profile there are enabled 'give view access to reports in public folders' and 'give view access to dashboards in public folders'.

[image]

When I enabled 'Manage Dashboards in Public Folders' for a profile, the user with this profile is able to see the dashboard, but now he has edit access, while I need only view access. So how to remove edit access and only keep view access?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for your first question**

(For non public folder dashboards) Go to that dashboard stored dashboard Folder >> Click
`Share` option then you can mention the `user`/`Role`/`Roles and internal subordinates` options to share the dashboard into other users with access as `View`, `Editor` and `Manager`.

**Answer for your Second question**

I can guess following points are possible to missing,

- Dashboard `Running User` is missing in your dashboard. Please ask admin to set dashboard `Running User` as `Specific user` or `Login as user` by clicking the gear icon for the dashboard `edit` page. Which will decide which user context the dashboard data need to show.
- If it's come from any package, please check the package access for the specific user.
- Please check the dashboard component using `source report` are coming from `public` folder or any `shared` folder. Because if `Source` reports are stored in any specific `shared` folder means, the users which view this dashboard need those report (`source report`) access to view the dashboard components.

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: I enabled 'Manage Dashboards in Public Folders' and now user can see the dashboard, but now he has edit access, so how to remove edit access and only keep view access? User has access to all dashboard and report folders.

Answer (score 0):

For Second Question

Ans:- Disable edit access in system permission under profiles.